# SPARQL dateTime subtraction with a particular format

Tags: sparql, rdf, rdfs, rdfstore

Here we see that when I try to subtract 2 datetime with angular brackets it doesnt seem to work but if the angular is removed it works fine.

what I am currently doing is generating triplets via a python library and it creates the triplets with angular brackets (serialization in turtle) and query runs after it, ofcourse we have tried a quick fix to fix the file before the query but is there a better way to do it?

```
PREFIX : <http://example.com/abc/abc#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
select ?diff where { 
    
    BIND("2020-09-21T12:47:50Z"^^<xsd:dateTime>  as ?diff1).
    BIND("2020-09-20T12:47:50Z"^^<xsd:dateTime>  as ?diff2).
    BIND(?diff2 - ?diff1 as ?diff).
}
```

## Update

work around for this

```
BIND(xsd:dateTime(STR(?diff2)) - xsd:dateTime(STR(?diff1)) as ?diff).
```

Comment: the notation `<xsd:dateTime>` is just "wrong", this would resolve to a) the base URI based on the document location when loading the data and b) to the SPARQL service host when querying

Comment: either use the prefixed form `xsd:dateTime` or the full URI form `<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime>`

Comment: yes it's the library which generates it in this form also when we upload it to the database it doesn't complain either... it's only while we query it doesn't work

Comment: fix the library issue or set the `BASE` when loading **and** querying

Comment: also when I try to check the datatype of the parameter it also recognizes it correctly with dateTime wise

Comment: how do we set the BASE? sorry I am new to this

Comment: `<xsd:dateTime>` is a relative IRI, which are resolved relative to the current base IRI. How to set the base IRI in Turtle is explained here: https://www.w3.org/TR/turtle/#sec-iri how to set it in the SPARQL query is stated here: https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#relIRIs

Comment: Subtracting two dateTimes is technically an extension because supporting xsd:duration, the result of subtracting to xsd:dateTime, is not requyired by the SPARQL 1.0 spec (or 1.1 but redstore supports 1.0).

Comment: PREFIX has no effect on `<...>`, only the bare "xsd:dateTime" form. `<xsd:dateTime>` is a URI in `xsd` URI scheme - which does not exist. BASE won't resolve it. It is legal in RDF - datatypes are not required to be from a fixed set of namespaces; it does not mean the engine knows anything about its semantics.

Comment: Yes base wont work…I tried to solve it by first casting it to string then recasting it to xsd:dateTime but again not happy witht the way it is done .. but do u think there is better way to solve it ?